# How can I get the ID of div inside a div wrapper. Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="data" class="grid grid-cols-2">
</div>
```

and I have a function that can append in `data` div:

```
function loadStaticBar(data) {
     let pl_name= `bar-${data.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`
        $('#data').append(`
        <div class="flex flex-col" id="${pl_name}-wrapper">
            <div class="static barchart" id="${pl_name}-plot">

            </div>
        </div>
        `)
}
```

The content of loadStaticBar(data) is a key and value it's a details for charts:

```
{id: 453, title: 'Bar Chart Example', select: 'bar-form', xtitle: 'Values', ytitle: 'Date', …}
```

Now, I'm trying to get all the IDs with the class `static`. I have tried:

```
$('#data').find('.static')
```

And I get `S.fn.init [prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]` inside of this are bunch of information. How can I get the IDs of the div that containing `static` class like this.

```
ids = [line-plot, bar-plot]
```

Comment: Can you also give us some indication about the possible content of your `data` object that is passed into the `loadStaticBar()` function?

Comment: I updated it sir

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the *updated* question could be:

```js
function loadStaticBar(data) {
 let pl_name= `bar-${data.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`
    $('#data').append(`
    <div class="flex flex-col" id="${pl_name}-wrapper">
        <div class="static barchart" id="${pl_name}-plot">

        </div>
    </div>
    `)
}
const data={id: 453, title: 'Bar Chart Example', select: 'bar-form', xtitle: 'Values', ytitle: 'Date'};

$(function(){
 loadStaticBar(data); // create the divs first !!!
 const ids=$("#data .static").get().map(el=>el.id);
 console.log(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="data" class="grid grid-cols-2">
</div>
```

As you want to receive a "proper" array instead of a jQuery object it makes sense to `.get()` the selected DOM elements first and then `.map()` them using the standard `Array`-method.

Incidentally, you can solve the originally posted question also without jQuery:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
 const ids=[...document.querySelectorAll("#data .static")].map(el=>el.id);
 console.log(ids);
});
```

```html
<div id="data" class="grid grid-cols-2">
 <div class="flex flex-col" id="line-wrapper">
  <div class="static linechart" id="line-plot">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="flex flex-col" id="bar-wrapper">
  <div class="static barchart" id="bar-plot">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an empty array

Comment: In case your script is placed above the `<body>` element you should place the place the action into a `$(function(){ ... })` that runs after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I tried your answer inside <script></script> below the body. I also updated my question. Still now getting the ids